# Can I change the value of a select box option using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-3.6

I need to verify that all of our dealers are being listed properly in my company's store locator.  To do so, I was thinking of scraping everything using Python.

I was able to find the search form using Selenium and fill out the location box with a city and state.  I have an issue with the search radius.  The values are set and the code looks like the following:

Code:

```
<select id="radius" name="radius">
  <option value="5">Within 5 miles</option>
  <option value="10">Within 10 miles</option>
  <option value="15">Within 15 miles</option>
  <option value="25">Within 25 miles</option>
  <option value="50" selected="selected">Within 50 miles</option>
  <option value="100">Within 100 miles</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is set the value of one option to 1000 in order to search within 1 thousand miles of the city/state I enter in order to return all possible results at the same time.

Is there a way to do this with Selenium?  I checked the docs, but couldn't find a way to change a value, only retrieve them.

I know it is possible to do using the RoboBrowser library, but it seems I can't use the same browser session between them.

Am I missing the part of Selenium that will let me do this?  Or is there a better library out there for achieving my goal?  I am using Python 3.6.  Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, Selenium cannot do this.

Comment: Maybe with a little bit of JavaScript? I don't think Selenium is capable of manipulating the DOM

Comment: IMO, this usecase defeats the purpose of **Automation Testing**. `Automation Testing is about automating the repetitive `Manual Testing` tasks. There are more useful tools available to achieve the same. But yes, Selenium can do that too. Voting to _Close_ this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB - I am trying to automate this, hence the question.  But, if you have a tool that is better suited for what I am trying to do, I would happily take recommendations. Hence the last question in my post: "Or is there a better library out there for achieving my goal?"

Comment: @JJAJ The solution (code / tool) depends on your business requirement.

Comment: @DebanjanB - I'm trying to get a list of all of our dealers from the dealer locator page.  It only gives 5 results per page and it is programmed for a max search radius of 100 miles.  Instead, I want to override the value of 100 miles and search within 1000 miles.  I know this distance will cover all the possibilities.  The rest is easy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A many have stated, this type of action is just not possible with Selenium.  After investigating some other solutions, I decided to go with the simple answer:

I used `input()` to freeze everything while I make the change I need manually, then continue by returning to the console and hitting any key to continue.  Not elegant, but it gets the job done with minimal input.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Selenium as that basically means changing the web application data. But more importantly why you need that while testing ??

Comment: We believe that not all of our dealers are being listed in the store locator.  If I run the SQL query alone, I get the expected results, but when we run it from the site, it seems like some are missing.  But, the only way we can compare is apples to apples.  I.E, I want to get the complete list from the store locator, then compare that with what the SQL query returns directly and see if the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a value from Select Box or drop down. But changing the value in HTML/Web page is not possible, as it is part of Web Application which can not control by the Selenium Scripting.